# By row, shift first time step to first non-zero column (lag), then create new variable

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have an example data.frame (`df`, below) which contains values (size) of a variable at three time steps `sz_t1`, `sz_t2`, `sz_t3`. The variables `t1_t2`, `t2_t3`, `t1_t3` are a binary indicator of whether an individual (`ID`) ‘survived’ from time step 1 – 2, 2 – 3, or 1 – 3.

Instead of using time steps, I would like to use ‘age’ as the unit for time. That is, use the first non-zero value per ID as the starting point. For example, if `sz_t1` is zero, `t1_t2` would be recorded as `NA`, but using ‘age’ if `sz_t1` is zero, but `sz_t2` is greater than zero than `age1_2` can be recorded with a zero or one outcome for survival. So if I use this `age` shifted time unit, I would also like to know the value (size) at that age (`sz_age1`, etc)

The r code below uses `ifelse` statements to achieve the desired results for the example data.frame (`df`). However, as the number of time steps increase I feel that there might be a less verbose, or ‘cleaner’ method to achieve the results I seek. As more time steps get added I am not sure I'll be able to grasp the `ifelse` chains.

I've attempted to find information creating groups based on first non-zero column index to then lag the those groups by the appropriate value. However, I did not find a way to do this, at least not in wide format, or for different lags per group.

Is there another r package or command that could acheive these results in an effort to reduce the chained `ifelse` length?

[image: screen grab of data.frame and desired output]

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, sz_t1 = c(0.5, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.25), sz_t2 = c(0.6, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.55, 0), sz_t3 = c(0, 0.35, 0.35, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ID", 
"sz_t1", "sz_t2", "sz_t3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

# did the id 'survive' from t1 to t2, etc
df$t1_t2 <- ifelse(df$sz_t1 > 0, ifelse(df$sz_t2 >0,1,0), NA)
df$t2_t3 <- ifelse(df$sz_t2 > 0, ifelse(df$sz_t3 >0,1,0), NA)
df$t1_t3 <- ifelse(df$sz_t1 > 0, ifelse(df$sz_t3 >0,1,0), NA)

# "age"
# did the id 'survive' from age1 to age2, etc
df$age1_2 <- ifelse(df$sz_t1 > 0, ifelse(df$sz_t2 >0,1,0),
                    ifelse(df$sz_t2 > 0, ifelse(df$sz_t3 >0,1,0), NA))
# if zero in first time step, age 2 to age 3 is NA as this time has yet to elapse
df$age2_3 <-ifelse(df$age1_2 > 0, ifelse(df$sz_t1 > 0,
                   ifelse(df$sz_t2 > 0, ifelse(df$sz_t3 > 0,1,0),NA),NA),NA)
# for the moment this is the same as df$t1_t3, need a t1 to get a value for age1_3, otherwise NA as the this time period has yet to elapse
df$age1_3 <- ifelse(df$sz_t1 > 0, ifelse(df$sz_t3 >0,1,0), NA)

# what was the size at the ages
df$sz_age1 <- ifelse(df$sz_t1 > 0, df$sz_t1, df$sz_t2)
df$sz_age2 <- ifelse(df$sz_t1 > 0, df$sz_t2, df$sz_t3)
df$sz_age3 <- ifelse(df$sz_t1 > 0, df$sz_t3, NA)
```

Comment: Please don't tag with packages you aren't using simply in the hope of attracting answers. I'm talking about `data.table` and `plyr`.

Comment: Is the `t1_t3` column really necessary? Just adding one more time step, it's going to be messy if you need, say `t1_t4`, `t2_t4`, `t3_t4`, adding `t-1` new columns for the `t`th time step. Things might be easier with a single time column (or perhaps a start-time and a stop-time column), a single age column (age at start time), and a single survival column instead of trying to combine [time and age] in one column group and [time and previous times] in another column group.

Comment: Upon further reflection the `t1_t3` column is not necessary. I'll will now consider your other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your making this a little more complicated than it needs to be. 
I am unclear if the 0 values in the sz columns are animal of z size (to small to measure) or that no measurement was taken because they were not observed?

One way to reduce the complexity of the code could be to substitute NAs for zeros where measurements were not taken because the animal had not entered the study.

```
df$sz_T1[df$sz_T1 == 0]<-NA


df$t1_t2<-as.numeric(df$sz_T1 * df$sz_T2)>0)
```

Than you can just multiply the 2 columns together and test if the product is >0.

This should help with generating the capture history and can be adapted for the survival from entry portion of your df and multiplying through to add your size measurements.